# Why won't my php script connect to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys,
I'm trying to make a full-text search bar and already my script wont work...
My php script is this...

```
<?php

MySQL_connect("hostname", "username", "password"); 
MySQL_select_db("our_db"); 
$query = " 
    SELECT * FROM articles 
    WHERE MATCH(title, body) AGAINST ('PHP') 
"; 
$sql = MySQL_query($query); 
/* output results */ 
?>
```

And when I try to preview it, it comes up with:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function MySQL_connect() 
 Error in line 12 (line 12:  MySQL_connect("hostname", "username", "password"); 
) 
 Server Error in '/' Application.
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HTTP Error 500 - Internal Server Error.

... if any of you guys can work it out it would be much appreciated... Thanks

Comment: 'mysql_connect', not 'MySQL_connect', etc

Comment: yeah... i tried that it didn't work, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your PHP configuration is not setup for mySQL. Try using the `phpinfo()` function to see if it is.

Comment: Just create a dummy script, with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then navigate to that script. It will dump a lot, including what extensions are configured. Just look for a mysql entry, it should have version info if installed. Otherwise there will not be a mysql entry, or it will state that it is not configured.

Comment: @Sam: well, you could start by googling it.

Comment: Yh it came up with the php page, but what am i looking for? :L

Comment: They are all slightly different, but basicall, just do a search for *mysql* and you should get 1 or 2 boxes that list information like *Client API version* or *mysql.default_host*. If the boxes aren't there, or have values that suggesting it isn't configured, contact your host.

Comment: i did a search for mysql and the sections they were under were: Path, MySqlnd and _SERVER["path"]

Comment: but i couldnt find client api or mysql.default_host...
Thanks for all the help though...

Comment: WAIT! I think it's because i didn't save it in the folder why my server accesses web pages... hang on